# Perl setpriority function on CentOS server

Tags: perl, centos, set, cpanel

I use CentOS 7 and cPanel on my server.  I am trying to figure out how to prioritize a Perl task to be LOW priority.

When I call setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, $$, 19), the task shows up in cPanel's Task Manager (TOP) list with a priority of 19.  But cPanel documentation says that Task Manager shows values from -20 to 20, where -20 is the lowest CPU utilization for that task.  So I try calling setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, $$, -19) but the task shows up in cPanel Task Manager as priority 0.

So I try calling getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, $$) right after setpriority.   If I call setpriority with a priority value of anything negative, getpriority returns a 0 for the current process.   If I call setpriority with any positive value, getpriority returns with the value I just specified.

It seems that Task Manager displays the same positive values I use in setpriority, but ignores any negative values I send in setpriority.

Is it possible to tell CentOS to prioritize the current process very LOW; that is, so it shows up in Task Manager with something like a -19 priority, which is very low according to the cPanel documentation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have it backwards. On modern Linux systems, the range is -20 to 19, where -20 is *highest* priority and 19 is the *lowest*. (It can go to 20 on some other systems.)

You were accidentally attempting to increase the priority when you provided negative numbers, but a lack of permissions (fortunately) prevented you from doing so, which is why the priority remained at the default 0. The first thing you have should have done is check for errors!

```
use constant PRIO_PROCESS => 0;

# $userland_priority ranges from -20 (highest) to 19 (lowest).
my $userland_priority = 19;

setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, $$, $userland_priority)
   or die("setpriority: $!\n");
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will contact cPanel to ask for further clarification about their Process Manager.  Like I said, when i called setpriority with a value of 19 (which I thought was lowest based on the Perl docs for setpriority, it showed up as 19 in Process Manager, whose docs say:
"Priority: A number between -20 and 20 that describes how much time the system uses to work on the process. -20 is the least CPU intensive, while 20 is the most CPU intensive." which appears to be the opposite of the setpriority value range.

Comment: cPanel is returning the priority you set, so it's simply is docs that are incorrect. Use the code I provided to set the lowest priority (least CPU).